# Persisting multiple records to the database

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form with multiple inputs changing one database column. So for example I have two select inputs, both changing the same database columns, let's say:

```
product_id: 1
category_id: 5

product_id: 1
category_id: 8
```

Having this in the database, I have two select inputs - first one to update the first record, and second to update the second record.

Form builder is just an input in the foreach loop.

And the controller:

```
    $data = $form->getData();
    foreach($data as $category)
    {
        var_dump($category);
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

This however throws an error that the category variable is not an object in the persis method.

For example if there's one select input the data object looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(MyBaze\AdminBundle\Entity\ProductCategory30)[444]
      private 'productId' => int 53655
      private 'categoryId' => int 294
  'categoryId' => int 293
```

And it also doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

EDIT.

```
<?php

// ...

class ChangeProductCategoryType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var int $categoriesCount
     */
    private $categoriesCount = 0;

    /**
     * @var array $choices
     */
    private $choices = [];

    /**
     * @var array $currentCategories
     */
    private $currentCategories = [];

    /**
     * Initialize basic variables
     *
     * @param $categoriesCount
     */
    public function __construct($categoriesCount, $choices, $currentCategories)
    {
        $this->categoriesCount = $categoriesCount;
        $this->choices = $choices;
        $this->currentCategories = $currentCategories;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $categoriesArray = [];
        foreach($this->choices as $category)
        {
            $categoriesArray[$category['id']] = $category['name'];
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < $this->categoriesCount; $i++)
        {
            $builder->add('categoryId', 'choice', [
                'required' => false,
                'choices' => $categoriesArray,
                'empty_value' => false,
                'label' => 'Product category',
                'data' => $this->currentCategories[$i]->getCategoryId()
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'changeProductCategory';
    }

} // End ChangeProductCategoryType
```

Comment: Can you shows us your form type source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing : never call the EntityManager flush function in a loop. You can persist many objects before using flush(). Use several flush will cause a big lack of performance.

Instead of :

```
$data = $form->getData();
foreach($data as $category)
{
    var_dump($category);
    $em->persist($category);
    $em->flush();
}
```

You should have :

```
$data = $form->getData();
foreach($data as $category)
{
    // Your business with $category
    $em->persist($category);
}
$em->flush();
```

I don't understand at all what you meant to do with your form builder, but I think this shall help you : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html.

If you can describe what you are trying to do, I will surely be able to help you more :).